# Geometric mean functions returning Inf

Tags: r, statistics

Trying to solve a homework problem:

I have two functions to get the geometric mean from 1000 observations from the exponential distribution with a rate of .01. The following keeps returning Inf.

```
gmean <- function(n)
{
    
  prod(n)^(1/length(n))
  
}

x<-rexp(1000,1/100)
    
    
    gmean(x)
```

but this does not

```
gmean1 <- function(n)
{
  
 exp(mean(log(n)))
  
}

x<-rexp(1000,1/100)
gmean1(x)
```

Why is this? I think it's something to do with the prod function but I'm not sure.

Comment: You vector is too large for prod to calculate so prod throws inf. Try rexp(10, 1/100)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that when you do `prod(n)` in your function, it calculates the result of this call before raising it to the power of `(1/length(n))`. Since the mean of `x` is about 100, you can expect this call to return a value with a similar order of magnitude to 100^1000, which is much higher than the maximum number that R will return (R will call anything above around 10^308 `Inf`).

Any mathematical operation you attempt on `Inf` will also return `Inf`, so your naive implementation will not work if `x` is greater than about 154:

```r
100^154
#> [1] 1e+308

100^155
#> [1] Inf
```

In actuality, because the majority of numbers are less than 100 in your sample, you might get to an x length of about 180 before you started generating `Inf`

In any case, it would be safer to stick to

```r
gmean <- function(n) exp(sum(log(n))/length(n))
```